# Remove all rotation from anchor in ArCore

Tags: java, android, matrix, arcore

So I'm building an app where all user-placed objects should face the same direction. For this I need to remove all rotation from the anchor on which the object is place on. This is the code for reading the pose from the anchor and placing the object:

```java
 for (ColoredAnchor coloredAnchor : anchors) {
        if (coloredAnchor.anchor.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                continue;
        }
        // Get the current pose of an Anchor in world space. The Anchor pose is updated
        // during calls to session.update() as ARCore refines its estimate of the world.
        coloredAnchor.anchor.getPose().toMatrix(anchorMatrix, 0);


        // Update and draw the model and its shadow.
        virtualObject.updateModelMatrix(anchorMatrix, scaleFactor / 12f);
        virtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, colorCorrectionRgba, arrowColor);
}
```

How can I remove the rotation from the matrix but keep the local position of the anchor?

I know you can use

```java
coloredAnchor.anchor.getPose().getRotationQuaternion();
```

to extract the rotation and

```java
Matrix.rotateM();
```

to rotate the anchor-matrix. But `rotateM` takes an angle in degrees as input where as `getRotationQuaternion()` outputs a different format. Maybe on could convert the output from the Quaternion to degrees and just rotate the matrix in the inverse direction?

All in all the 3D-Model should always face the same direction in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. I'm converting the values from the Quaternion to Euler angles ([Conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles)). After that im using the calculated rotations in inverse on the ar-object. I need to do more testing but it works fine so far.

```java
 coloredAnchor.anchor.getPose().toMatrix(anchorMatrix, 0);

double w = coloredAnchor.anchor.getPose().qw();
double x = coloredAnchor.anchor.getPose().qx();
double y = coloredAnchor.anchor.getPose().qy();
double z = coloredAnchor.anchor.getPose().qz();

double xAngle = 0;
double yAngle = 0;
double zAngle = 0;

double sinr_cosp = 2 * (w * x + y * z);
double cosr_cosp = 1 - 2 * (x * x + y * y);
xAngle = Math.atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp);

double sinp = 2 * (w * y - z * x);
if (Math.abs(sinp) >= 1) {
    yAngle = Math.copySign(Math.PI / 2, sinp); // use 90 degrees if out of range
} else {
    yAngle = Math.asin(sinp);
}

double siny_cosp = 2 * (w * z - x * y);
double cosy_cosp = 1 - 2 * (y * y + z * z);

zAngle = Math.atan2(siny_cosp, cosy_cosp);

xAngle = Math.toDegrees(xAngle);
yAngle = Math.toDegrees(yAngle);
zAngle = Math.toDegrees(zAngle);

Matrix.rotateM(anchorMatrix, 0, (float) -xAngle, 1f, 0f, 0f);
Matrix.rotateM(anchorMatrix, 0, (float) -yAngle + DYNAMIC_BUILDING_FIX, 0f, 1f, 0f);
Matrix.rotateM(anchorMatrix, 0, (float) -zAngle, 0f, 0f, 1f);

virtualObject.updateModelMatrix(anchorMatrix, scaleFactor / 12f);
virtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, colorCorrectionRgba, arrowColor);
```

It's a quite lengthy and hacky solution though, maybe someone has a better idea how to solve it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is DYNAMIC_BUILDING_FIX value? Appreciate your answer +1 for this.